# Recover cost function from profit function

Tags: microeconomics

How do I recover the cost function from the profit function?

Suppose I have $$ \pi(p, w_1, w_2) = p^3 \cdot w_1 \cdot w_2 $$.

How do I get the cost function?

Using Hotelling's lemma I get the supply function: $$ y_s(p) = \frac{\partial  \pi(p, w_1, w_2)}{\partial p} = 3 p^2 \cdot w_1 \cdot w_2$$ and the input demands:
$$z_1(p, w)= - \frac{\partial  \pi(p, w_1, w_2)}{\partial w_l} = - p^3 w_2 $$ and $$z_2(p, w)= - \frac{\partial  \pi(p, w_1, w_2)}{\partial w_2} = - p^3 w_1 $$but what is the next step?

Note that the functional forms are hypothetical and highly probable to be invalid.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you ask yourself the following questions:

- If $\tilde{z}(y;w)$ is the input demand from cost minimization, can there be any difference between $\tilde{z}\big(y(p);w\big) \equiv \hat{z} (p;w)$ and $z(p;w)$ from Hotelling's lemma and profit maximization?
- Even if $\tilde{z}(y;w)$ is a correspondance rather than a function, is there any difference between $ p \hat{z} (p;w) = p \tilde{z}\big(y(p);w\big) = c(y;w) $ and $p z(p;w)$ (where the later are dot products).

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

If you have recovered the supply function $y_s(\bullet)$, from the equation $$Q=y_s(p,\mathbf{r})$$ hopefully you could solve for p, e.g. $p=f\left(Q,\mathbf{r}\right)$. If the firm is maximizing profits, the equation $p=f\left(Q,\mathbf{r}\right)$ is equivalent to the condition $p=C'\left(Q,\mathbf{r}\right)$.
So, one recovers $$C\left(Q,\mathbf{r}\right)=\int {f\left(Q,\mathbf{r}\right)dQ}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you know quantity as a function of prices, then you know revenue as a function of prices.  If you also know profits, then cost are straightforwardly the difference.

Comment: It would help if you elaborated a little (and addressed the specific question mentioned in the original post).